# Node.js: how to poll a web resource for change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, resources, file-monitoring

Using node.js how do I poll a web resource (eg. example.org/data.json) for change in a asynchronous way so I can notify the clients whenever a certain resource has changed ?

I'm looking for a lib or at least a somewhat more elegant way to archive this rather than downloading the file myself, calculating and comparing the hashes every few seconds.

Everything I found so far is using inotify or fswatch under the hood so it cant be used for non local files.

Comment: unless you push it from the remote resource server, polling is as good as it gets, and shouldn't be so complicated as to need a lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the Last-Modified Header field, if this is supported by the web resource.

Comment: Good idea, while this would avoid the hashing and downloading I'd still have to implement the logic to check for a change myself. I think this kind of task is so trivial that it should have been implemented in a lib already and i don't want to reinvent the wheel a 265th time if not necessary...